# How I can stop a Azure VM without deallocating via Portal

Tags: azure, azure-cli

If I work with VMs from Azure CLI, I can *start*, *stop* and *deallocate* my VM. It works like expected.

If I use the portal web interface, I see the start function and a stop function. But this *stop* function works like *stop and deallocate*. How can I stop my VM using the web interface like CLI *stop* without deallocation?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but i don't think that's possible. You can log in the vm and power off the OS in the vm, to get the VM in stopped, non-deallocated state. However, stopping the vm from the web interface with the stop button, will put the VM in deallocated state. Keep in mind that in non-deallocated state you're still using Azure resources, and will be charged for it.